# View edit history of my answer

Tags: support

I don't *think* this is a duplicate, although I'd be suprised if it wasn't.

I wanted to know (I'm sure it was fairly easy) how to access the edit history for an answer of mine? Someone suggested an edit for it, it had since been approved, but I don't know what exactly has changed?

Actually, I seen what was changed, but I'm sure what was added was already there before, can I possibly see a **complete edit history** of the answer?

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15249805/1039608

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click the time of the edit, you will get to the revision (and list of all revisions for that post).

[image]

Seems they added the missing variable name to your code snippet. =)

Comment: That's it! Thanks :). Yeah that's weird, I was sure I put it in there, oh well! 4 people upvoted without even checking! Shame on them :).

Comment: The answer's intuitive once you see it, though I didn't get it until I saw your answer.  This worked for me, thanks.